# Find variable word and replace it in file using Bash

Tags: bash, sed

I have a file and from this file I am trying to find a word and replace it with another word using Bash. I am using sed to do this and please note that the word that I am looking for is an output from a command. So I am trying to find a word, which is the output of a command, and replace it with another word and override the previous word.

This is my code:

```
File=file.txt
File2=file2.txt
min=$(cat $File2 | grep word);  
sed -i 's/$min/max/g' $File
```

It's not producing any error, but I am unable to find the word in order to replace it. When I manually type the word rather than using the variable "$min" it works just fine. So when I do this, it works:

```
sed -i 's/min/max/g' $File
```

but when I do this, it doesn't:

```
 sed -i 's/$min/max/g' $File
```

I am thinking maybe sed doesn't accept variables as a search string. Any idea how I can achieve this?

thank you.

Comment: Variables aren't expanded within single quotes.

Comment: Thanks for. I changed it to double quotes and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

Use double quotes for the sed expression, this should work:

```
sed -i "s/$min/max/g" $File
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help :)